# center a label in an area inside a GridLayout

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I'm just trying to center a label in a GridLayout that is inside a popUP:

```
    public class PopUpAlert extends  Window implements View{
        
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public PopUpAlert() {
        
        super("Inserimento"); 
        center();
        setWidth("1500px");
        
        GridLayout layoutpopUp = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        
        final TextField textDescrizione3 = new TextField("Descrizione3");
        final TextField textDescrizione4 = new TextField("Descrizione4");
        Label label = new Label("label");
        label.setSizeUndefined();
        layoutpopUp.addComponent(label, 0,0,1,0);   
        layoutpopUp.addComponent(textDescrizione3,0,1); 
        layoutpopUp.addComponent(textDescrizione4,1,1); 
        
        layoutpopUp.setMargin(true);
        
        layoutpopUp.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layoutpopUp);
}
```

The result is this one:
[image]

What I want is just center label in the center of the cell area that is identified by
layoutpopUp.addComponent(label, 0,0,1,0);

I've tried almost everything

- layoutpopUp.setComponentAlignment(label, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
- Component c = layoutpopUp.getComponent(1,0);
  layoutpopUp.setComponentAlignment(c, Alignment.TOP_CENTER);
- as indicated in
  [Vaadin Alignment with GridLayout to center over cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755012/vaadin-alignment-with-gridlayout-to-center-over-cells)

but no one will center the label above and in the center of Descrizione3 and Descrizione4;

Also I have copied the example at https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout, but to me the button 3x1 is on the left side of the cell;
I'm going to get crazy;